# ASP proper config to allow CORS in a asmx webservice for POST requests

Tags: web-services, web-config, cors, polymer-1.0

I´m trying to setup a server capable to handle CORS, but also capable to return the response in json format.
Tried with various config schemes, but no luck.

I need to do my Ajax requests via POST. With my actual config i´m able to do requests via GET, but currently my response always is encapsulated in XML format.

As stated in [ResponseFormat.Json returns xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611134/responseformat-json-returns-xml) , my requests must be 'application/json' but when I try to do it in this way I'm receiving a preflight message (Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404).

My web.config (allowing CORS via GET) currently is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <!--<add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>-->
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>  
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <....>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /><remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /><remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" /><add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /></handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I´m using iron-polymer for the Ajax-requests and combined various content-types. Currently i´m getting my data via GET using 'content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" handle-as="document"'.

I´m having difficulties to process the response due such XML encapsulation. Below are two examples of received responses. How to extract the contents ?

1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <string xmlns="http://my.domain/">EF7B48E346BC537F98F9696304CECAFE</string>
```

2:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfCiudad xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://my.domain/">
  <Ciudad>
    <Codigo>32</Codigo>
    <Nombre>BOGOTA</Nombre>
    <CodigoDepartamento>Z03</CodigoDepartamento>
  </Ciudad>
  <Ciudad>
    <Codigo>133</Codigo>
    <Nombre>CALI</Nombre>
    <CodigoDepartamento>Z01</CodigoDepartamento>
  </Ciudad>
  <Ciudad>
    <Codigo>53</Codigo>
    <Nombre>CARTAGENA</Nombre>
    <CodigoDepartamento>Z13</CodigoDepartamento>
  </Ciudad>
  <Ciudad>
    <Codigo>30</Codigo>
    <Nombre>MEDELLIN</Nombre>
    <CodigoDepartamento>Z04</CodigoDepartamento>
  </Ciudad>
</ArrayOfCiudad>'
```